# Terms aggregation (to achieve hierarchical faceting) query performance slow

Tags: elasticsearch, hierarchy, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am indexing metric names in elastic search. Metric names are of the form `foo.bar.baz.aux`. Here is the index I use.

```
{
    "index": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "prefix-test-analyzer": {
                    "filter": "dotted",
                    "tokenizer": "prefix-test-tokenizer",
                    "type": "custom"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "dotted": {
                    "patterns": [
                        "([^.]+)"
                    ],
                    "type": "pattern_capture"
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "prefix-test-tokenizer": {
                    "delimiter": ".",
                    "type": "path_hierarchy"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

{
    "metrics": {
        "_routing": {
            "required": true
        },
        "properties": {
            "tenantId": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "unit": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "metric_name": {
                "index_analyzer": "prefix-test-analyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "keyword",
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above index creates the following terms for a metric name `foo.bar.baz`

```
foo
bar
baz
foo.bar
foo.bar.baz
```

If I have bunch of metrics, like below

```
a.b.c.d.e
a.b.c.d
a.b.m.n
x.y.z
```

I have to write a query to grab the nth level of tokens. In the example above

```
for level = 0, I should get [a, x] 
for level = 1, with 'a' as first token I should get [b]
               with 'x' as first token I should get [y]  
for level = 2, with 'a.b' as first token I should get [c, m]
```

I couldn't think of any other way, other than to write terms aggregation. To figure out level 2 tokens of `a.b`, here is the query I came up with.

```
time curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/metrics_alias/metrics/_search\?pretty\&routing\=12345 -d '{
      "size": 0,
      "query": {
        "term": {
            "tenantId": "12345"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
          "metric_name_tokens": {
              "terms": {
                  "field" : "metric_name",
                  "include": "a[.]b[.][^.]*",
                  "execution_hint": "map",
                  "size": 0
              }
          }
      }
  }'
```

This would result in the following buckets. I parse the output and grab [c, m] from there.

```
"buckets" : [ {
     "key" : "a.b.c",
     "doc_count" : 2
   }, {
     "key" : "a.b.m",
     "doc_count" : 1
 } ]
```

So far so good. The query works great for most of the tenants(notice `tenantId` `term` query above). For certain tenants which has large amounts of data (around 1 Mil), the performance is really slow. I am guessing all the terms aggregation takes time.

I am wondering if terms aggregation is the right choice for this kind of data and also looking for other possible kinds of queries.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you need. Do you need the counts? Or do you need c and m? Or do you need the documents containing: a.b.c.d.e - a.b.c.d - a.b.m.n?

Comment: I just need c and m.

Comment: @JettroCoenradie I just need c and m. Basically what ever are the next level of possible tokens for a given prefix.

Comment: How does the cluster look like? (how many nodes, how much RAM, how many CPU cores, what's the heap size) `metrics_alias` how many indices does it touch? How large are they? When you run a "heavy" query (with millions of metrics) how is the CPU and heap usage for the nodes?

Comment: @AndreiStefan Its a 3 node cluster with 125G RAM and 40 cores. ES runs with a heap size of 31G. metric_alias only touches 2 indices (one is not being updated anymore). Around 20GB of data. I dont see anything different in CPU and heap usage when running the query.

Comment: I'd suggest to "mirror" the filter at the aggregations level in the `query` part as well. So, for `a.b.` matching, use this as a query: `  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "tenantId": 123
          }
        },
        {
          "prefix": {
            "metric_name": {
              "value": "a.b."
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }` and keep the same `aggs` section. Test this and let me know how it goes. Run it multiple times, not just once.

Comment: Also, another problem with the query is `"size": 0` for the aggregation part.  Do you really need the aggregation to return all the buckets, no matter how many they are. Can you test the query with something like `"size": 100` for example?

Comment: Whoever downvoted the question, may I know the reason for it?

Comment: @AndreiStefan Changing the size to 100, didnt have much effect. Total time for the query remained the same.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Adding a regexp filter which mirrors the one at aggregation level did have a great impact. The run time of the query I was testing came down from 23 secs to 11 seconds.  But the performance is still not good enough.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Adding a regexp filter which mirrors the one at aggregation level really helps as we query for higher levels of tokens. For ex: next levels of a.b.c.d. But for lower levels like a.b, it is better but still not as good as we would like.

Comment: Glad one of those made a difference. Now tell me what's the size on disk of those two indices. 20gb only primaries or 20gb primaries+replicas? How many primaries and how many replicas do the two indices have?

Comment: Also, please remove `"execution_hint": "map"` and let Elasticsearch use the defaults.

Comment: The query which runs in 11 secs now took around 50 secs if I remove "execution_hint": "map"

Comment: The size of 20GB I gave you earlier was of primaries. Total size is around 60GB. The metric_alias is pointing to two indexes. One index has 15GB and the other index has 45GB of data in total size. Each index has 5 primary shards and 10 replica shards.

Comment: `The query which runs in 11 secs now took around 50 secs if I remove "execution_hint": "map"`... hmm... and you if you still have `execution_hint` not included and run the query multiple times (10 times let's say), it's still returning in 50 secs?

Comment: The ran the query after removing execution_hint 10 times and these are the run times(rounded) 59,51,23,55,47,23,43,48,1min,1min

Comment: Got it. Put it back in then :-). Then run the query several times. After 5-6 runs, run it one more time and be prepared to get a list of `hot_threads` from the cluster: `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_nodes/hot_threads?threads=5000"`. So, **while the query is running (11 seconds)**, run the previous `hot_threads`  command **twice** at 2-3 seconds interval and save each run in a separate text file. Use `gist` to share them.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Here you go. https://gist.github.com/ChandraAddala/d70904b90027217db4192e34b70dde85

Comment: Btw, I suggested using `prefix` filter, not `regexp`. My feeling is that the `prefix` one is quicker and, also, it does the same thing (from filtering point of view) as the regexp one. Please, try with `prefix` not `regexp` as a filter.

Comment: And yes, the search part is spending most of the time in the regexp inside the aggregation. As suggested before, try to use `prefix` in the filter part and see how it goes. And, as you do know - the regex in the aggregation only as I don't see other way to filter the terms.

Comment: Actually regexp would work better for me as someone could do a search like a.b.*.d to find the next token. Also I noted that regexp is running faster than prefix query. Using prefix query takes around 12-13 seconds on an average and using regexp takes 11-12 seconds on an average.

Comment: If I run several times prefix query also runs around 11-12 seconds

Comment: The only other thing I could think of is to relieve the pressure at searching time by moving it at indexing time. What I mean by that: at indexing time, in your own application or whatever indexing method you are using, split the text to be indexed programaticaly (not ES doing it) and index each element in the hierarchy in a separate field. For example `a.b` in `field2`, `a.b.c` in `field3` and so on. This for the same document. Then, at search time, you look at specific fields depending on what the search text is. This whole idea, though, requires some additional work outside ES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- "mirror" the filter at the aggregations level in the query part as well. So, for `a.b.` matching, use the following as a query and keep the same aggs section:

```
"bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "term": {
        "tenantId": 123
      }
    },
    {
      "prefix": {
        "metric_name": {
          "value": "a.b."
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

or even use `regexp` with the same regular expression as in the aggregation part. In this way, the aggregations will have to evaluate less buckets as the documents that reach the aggregation part will be less.
You mentioned that `regexp` is working better for you, my initial guess was that the `prefix` would perform better.

- change `"size": 0` from aggregations to `"size": 100`. After testing you mentioned this doesn't make any difference
- remove `"execution_hint": "map"` and let Elasticsearch use the defaults. After testing you mentioned that the default `execution_hint` was performing far worse.
- the only other thing I could think of is to relieve the pressure at searching time by moving it at indexing time. What I mean by that: at indexing time, in your own application or whatever indexing method you are using, split the text to be indexed programaticaly (not ES doing it) and index each element in the hierarchy in a separate field. For example `a.b` in `field2`, `a.b.c` in `field3` and so on. This for the same document. Then, at search time, you look at specific fields depending on what the search text is. This whole idea, though, requires some additional work outside ES.

From all the suggestions above the first one had the greatest impact: queries response times improved from 23 secs to 11 seconds.

Comment: As per your suggestions for strings a.b.c.d.e, a.b.x.y, I will index index [a], [a.b], [a.b.c], [a.b.c.d], [a.b.c.d.e], [a.b.x], [a.b.x.y] separately, then how do I search to get all tokens which follow the prefix a.b?

Comment: For a document you would have this structure: `{"tenantId":123,"metric_name1":["a","x"],"metric_name2":["a.b","x.y"],"metric_name3":["a.b.c","a.b.m","x.y.z"],"metric_name4":["a.b.c.d","a.b.m.n"],"metric_name5":["a.b.c.d.e"]}`. All the `metric_name*` fields will be using the `keyword` analyzer or anything that will not split it. The query itself (because you want to allow your users to search for `a.b.*.d` and not only `prefix` queries) should be something like `"query_string": {
            "default_field": "metric_name*",
            "query": "a.b.*.d"
          }`.

Comment: The aggregations will be something like this though `"aggs": {
    "metric_name_tokens": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "metric_name3",
        "size": 0
      }
    }
  }`. So, basically, for a `a.b.*.d` search you are interested in what comes after `a.b.` only. And you'd be using the `metric_name3` field (the one with three levels of hierarchy). I'd be curious what to see what performance you get, though, from the `query_string` query. The aggregation part will be far lighter.

Comment: Writing the previous comment I had **another idea**: if the `query_string` above doesn't offer better performance over the `regexp` you use now, you can keep both approaches in the same index. Meaning you use `metric_name` with your custom analyzer (as you do now), **but also** you add the `metric_name*` fields that I suggested above and you will only be using `metric_name*` in aggregations (like I showed above).

Comment: When I said a.b.*.d. I meant with prefix as a.b.*.d. For input strings [a.b.x.d.e, a.b.y.d.f] with prefix of a.b.*.d, the next level of tokens would be [e. f]. But I believe the idea you had suggested handles this case.